# Using spaces in XSLT attribute names

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <document>
      <name>Example</name>
      <date>2020-10-31</date>
      <level>X_LEGAL_ABC</level>
      <bundle>
         <b001>E_AT01</b001>
         <example_id>00000000000007372165</example_id>
         <field>
            <field_value>EUR</field_value>
            <fieldname>CUR007</fieldname>
         </field>
         <field>
            <field_value>2018-06-30</field_value>
            <fieldname>C207</fieldname>
         </field>
         <field>
            <field_value>2014-07-01</field_value>
            <fieldname>C206</fieldname>
         </field>
      </bundle>
      <bundle>
         <b001>E_AT01</b001>
         <example_id>00000000000007372163</example_id>
         <field>
            <field_value>EUR</field_value>
            <fieldname>CUR007</fieldname>
         </field>
         <field>
            <field_value>2020-05-31</field_value>
            <fieldname>C207</fieldname>
         </field>
         <field>
            <field_value>2014-06-01</field_value>
            <fieldname>C206</fieldname>
         </field>
      </bundle>
</document>
</root>
```

With the following XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <xsl:stylesheet version='1.1' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/> 
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <document>
            <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="/root/document/name"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="date"><xsl:value-of select="/root/document/date"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="level"><xsl:value-of select="/root/document/level"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="/root/document/bundle">
        <bundle>
            <xsl:attribute name="Example_id"><xsl:value-of select="example_id"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="B001"><xsl:value-of select="B001"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="./field">
        
                <field>
                <xsl:attribute name="FIELDVALUE"><xsl:value-of select="field_value"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="FIELDNAME"><xsl:value-of select="fieldname"/></xsl:attribute>
                </field>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </bundle>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </document>
        
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This delivers me a working new XML format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document name="Example" date="2020-10-31" level="X_LEGAL_ABC">
   <bundle Example_id="00000000000007372165" B001="">
      <field FIELDVALUE="EUR" FIELDNAME="CUR007"/>
      <field FIELDVALUE="2018-06-30" FIELDNAME="C207"/>
      <field FIELDVALUE="2014-07-01" FIELDNAME="C206"/>
   </bundle>
   <bundle Example_id="00000000000007372163" B001="">
      <field FIELDVALUE="EUR" FIELDNAME="CUR007"/>
      <field FIELDVALUE="2020-05-31" FIELDNAME="C207"/>
      <field FIELDVALUE="2014-06-01" FIELDNAME="C206"/>
   </bundle>
</document>
```

However, i would like to have the field FIELDVALUE displayed as FIELD VALUE.
So with a blank space in between.
Is this possible within an XSLT file?

Can i change:
<xsl:attribute name="FIELDVALUE"

Into something like:
<xsl:attribute name="FIELD VALUE"

Is this possible? Because if i try to run it, it does not work.

I'm new to this XSLT work, so any help would be appreciated.

Best regards,

Michael

Comment: You can find some information on the subject here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277297/can-xml-attributes-have-spaces. I would say it's just asking for trouble. What would the benefit be of having that space in the attribute name?

Comment: XSLT is designed to generate well-formed XML, and well-formed XML does not allow spaces in attribute names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible*, because the XML [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-Name) does not allow spaces in the names of elements and attributes.

---

(*) It is *kind* of possible, if you construct your output as text - but the result will not be a well-formed XML document.

Comment: Pure out of curiosity, do you have an example how it would work then and what it would look like?

Comment: It's a horrible hack and a total waste of time - but you can see how it could "work" here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtDu. Of course, the result will be rejected by any XML parser.